# Using Python to use a website's search function

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to use a search function of a website with this code structure:

```
<div class='search'>
<div class='inner'>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/gr/el/products" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
<label for='query'>Ενδιαφέρομαι για...</label>
<fieldset>
<input class="search-input" data-search-url="/gr/el/products/autocomplete.json" id="text_search" name="query" placeholder="Αναζητήστε προϊόν" type="text" />
<button type='submit'>Αναζήτηση</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

with this python script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'}



payload = {
    'query':'test'
}

r = requests.get('http://www.pharmacy295.gr',data = payload ,headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
products = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'name'})
print(products)
```

This code came as a result of extensive searches on this website on how to do this task, however I never seem to manage to get any search results - just the main page of the website.

Comment: Please give some detail on what you're trying to achieve, what you have tried and what results you've had so far. It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: I am just trying to use the search function of the website pharmacy295.gr using python requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `products` to your url and it will work fine, the method is get in the form and the form shows also the url. If you are unsure crack open  use the developer console on firefox or chrome you can see exactly how the the request is made

```
payload = {
    'query':'neutrogena',

}

r = requests.get('http://www.pharmacy295.gr/products',data = payload ,headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
products = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'name'})
print(products)
```

Output:

```
[<span class="name">NEUTROGENA - Hand &amp; Nail Cream - 75ml</span>, <span class="name">NEUTROGENA - Hand Cream (Unscented) - 75ml</span>, <span class="name">NEUTROGENA - PROMO PACK 1+1 \u0394\u03a9\u03a1\u039f  Lip Moisturizer - 4,8gr</span>, <span class="name">NEUTROGENA - Lip Moisturizer with Nordic Berry - 4.9gr</span>]
```

Also if you prefer you can get the data as json:

```
In [13]: r = requests.get('http://www.pharmacy295.gr/el/products/autocomplete.json',data = payload ,headers = headers)

In [14]: print(r.json())
[{u'title': u'NEUTROGENA - Hand & Nail Cream - 75ml', u'discounted_price': u'5,31 \u20ac', u'photo': u'/system/uploads/asset/data/12584/tiny_108511.jpg', u'brand': u'NEUTROGENA ', u'path': u'/products/7547', u'price': u'8,17 \u20ac'}, {u'title': u'NEUTROGENA - Hand Cream (Unscented) - 75ml', u'discounted_price': u'4,03 \u20ac', u'photo': u'/system/uploads/asset/data/4689/tiny_102953.jpg', u'brand': u'NEUTROGENA ', u'path': u'/products/3958', u'price': u'6,20 \u20ac'}, {u'title': u'NEUTROGENA - PROMO PACK 1+1 \u0394\u03a9\u03a1\u039f  Lip Moisturizer - 4,8gr', u'discounted_price': u'3,91 \u20ac', u'photo': u'/system/uploads/asset/data/5510/tiny_118843.jpg', u'brand': u'NEUTROGENA ', u'path': u'/products/4644', u'price': u'4,60 \u20ac'}, {u'title': u'NEUTROGENA - Lip Moisturizer with Nordic Berry - 4.9gr', u'discounted_price': u'2,91 \u20ac', u'photo': u'/system/uploads/asset/data/12761/tiny_126088.jpg', u'brand': u'NEUTROGENA ', u'path': u'/products/7548', u'price': u'4,48 \u20ac'}]
```

Comment: Good find with the json request! That site is very liberal in what they accept in their HTTP requests, e.g. sending a `GET` with `requests.get()` with the `data` parameter sends the query parameters in the request body, not the URL's query string. Although the site seems happy enough with it, HTTP servers are not strictly required to accept parameters from the HTTP body of `GET` requests. To be safe I suggest using the `params` parameter instead of `data`.

Comment: @mhawke,the form data is just going to get appended to the url with a get request so you you could just use str.format ?query={}.format... and forget the data

Comment: You could, but when query parameters are specified as a dictionary via `params` `requests.get()` will URL encode them for you. They will be passed in the URL's query string (correct) instead of the request body (not incorrect, but it depends on the server whether it will process them).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the URL is wrong. You are using `http://www.pharmacy295.gr` but you should be using `http://www.pharmacy295.gr/gr/el/products`. This URL can actually be simplified to `http://www.pharmacy295.gr/products`.

Also are making a `GET` request so, rather than `data=payload`, try `params=payload`.

`data` is for POST requests.

Here is the documentation for [`requests.get()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

Comment: Still does not seem to work :/. Does not matter if I am using params/data or get/post(tried every possible combination).

Comment: Check my update. I think you are using the wrong URL. The form action is `/gr/el/products`, so that should be in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `r = requests.post('http://www.pharmacy295.gr',data = payload ,headers = headers)`

GET requests also ignore the data...

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'}

payload = {
    'query':'test',

}

r = requests.get('http://www.pharmacy295.gr/products',data = payload ,headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
products = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'name'})
print(products)
```